# Scrolling Text Widget with Mousewheel when filled with Widgets (python, tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter, widget

I use a disabled text widget filled with labels, to make a scrollable frame.
This works just fine, except for one thing: when the mouse is over a label, then scrolling the mouse wheel no longer gets registered.

I have below a simple demonstration script, where you will see that you can scroll when the mouse is over an empty part of the text widget,  but cannot scroll anymore when you are hovering over a button (in the example I just used buttons, same effect as labels).

So very concretely my question: how can I make the text widget scrollable even when the mouse hovers over a widget?

```
from tkinter import Tk, Button, Text,Scrollbar

class test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.win = Tk()
        text = Text(self.win, width=40, height=10, wrap = "none")
        ys = Scrollbar(self.win, orient = 'vertical', command = text.yview)
        text['yscrollcommand'] = ys.set
        text.grid(column = 0, row = 0, sticky = 'nwes')
        ys.grid(column = 1, row = 0, sticky = 'ns')
        for x in range(1,100):
            b = Button(text, text='Push Me')
            text.window_create("end", window=b)
            text.insert("end",'\n')
        self.win.mainloop()

test = test()
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I just found an answer. The problem lies, partly, in that there was a difference between working with Linux and Windows when binding Mousewheel to a widget.

So in addition to the above I made this code, to bind the mousewheel to the buttons. Problem solved, albeit, in my opionion, apparently unnecesarily complex. It would be nicer if the Text Widget would still register scrolling despite the presence of other widgets inside of it. :

```
b = Button(self.text, text="Push Me")
b.bind("<Button-4>", self.on_mousewheel)
b.bind("<Button-5>", self.on_mousewheel)

def on_mousewheel(self,event):
    if event.num==4:
        self.text.yview("scroll",-1,"units")
    else:
        self.text.yview("scroll",1,"units")
```

Update:

```
self.text.bind_all("<Button-4>", self.on_mousewheel)
self.text.bind_all("<Button-5>", self.on_mousewheel)
```

works also, so that not every individual Button or Label needs its own binding.